# Why does my nim game always choose pile A?

Tags: c++, if-statement, while-loop

I'm trying to make a game of nim, but when the program asks the user which pile they want to choose from, either A, B, or C, the program always says that the user chose pile A and removes the counters from pile A, even if the user chooses pile B or C.

I have looked over my code a lot and see no reason this would happen. All of the indentation and parenthesis check out and look fine. I tried moving the while statement and getting rid of the individual pile functions, but none of that changes anything.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string player1() {

        string player1;

        cout << "Player one, what is your name?" << endl;
        cin >> player1;

        return player1;
}


string player2() {

        string player2;

        cout << "Player two, what is your name?" << endl;
        cin >> player2;

        return player2;
}

int main() {

        string name1 = player1();
        string name2 = player2();

        int pile1 = 8;
        int pile2 = 10;
        int pile3 = 7;

//      while (pile1 >= 0 && pile2 >= 0 && pile3 >= 0) {

        char which_pile;
        int counters;


        cout << name1 << ", what pile do you want to choose from?" << endl;
        cin >> which_pile;

        while (pile1 >= 0 && pile2 >= 0 && pile3 >= 0) {

                if(which_pile == 'A' || 'a') {

                        cout << "You have chosen pile A. How many counters do you want to take?" << endl;
                        cin >> counters;

                        pile1 -= counters;

                        cout << "\n" << pile1 << endl;
                        cout << pile2 << endl;
                        cout << pile3 << "\n" << endl;


                } else if(which_pile == 'B' || 'b') {

                        cout << "You have chosen pile B. How many counters do you want to take?" << endl;
                        cin >> counters;

                        pile2 -= counters;
                        cout << "\n" << pile1 << endl;
                        cout << pile2 << endl;
                        cout << pile3 << "\n" << endl;

                } else if(which_pile == 'C' || 'c') {

                        cout << "You have chosen pile C. How many counters do you want to take?" << endl;
                        cin >> counters;

                        pile3 -= counters;
                        cout << "\n" << pile1 << endl;
                        cout << pile2 << endl;
                        cout << pile3 << "\n" << endl;

                } else {

                        cout << "Bad input." << endl;
                }

        cout << name2 << ", what pile do you want to choose from?" << endl;
        cin >> which_pile;

                if(which_pile == 'A' || 'a') {

                        cout << "You have chosen pile A. How many counters do you want to take?" << endl;
                        cin >> counters;

                        pile1 -= counters;

                        cout << "\n" << pile1 << endl;
                        cout << pile2 << endl;
                        cout << pile3 << "\n" << endl;

                } else if(which_pile == 'B' || 'b') {

                        cout << "You have chosen pile B. How many counters do you want to take?" << endl;
                        cin >> counters;

                        pile2 -= counters;
                        cout << "\n" << pile1 << endl;
                        cout << pile2 << endl;
                        cout << pile3 << "\n" << endl;

                } else if(which_pile == 'C' || 'c') {

                        cout << "You have chosen pile C. How many counters do you want to take?" << endl;
                        cin >> counters;

                        pile3 -= counters;
                        cout << "\n" << pile1 << endl;
                        cout << pile2 << endl;
                        cout << pile3 << "\n" << endl;

                } else {

                        cout << "Bad input." << endl;
                }
        }

        return 0;
}
```

I expect if the user chooses pile B or C, the program says you have chosen pile B or C, and then removes the counters from pile B or C, but the program always chooses pile A and removes counters from pile A.

Comment: What did you observe when stepping through your code line by line with the debugger?

Comment: A condition like `which_pile == 'A' || 'a'` does *not* work as you seem to expect. You must explicitly compare `which_pile` with both alternatives. Or use e.g. [`std::toupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper) or [`std::tolower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower), as in `std::toupper(which_pile) == 'A'`. You can also use a `switch` statement instead.

Comment: There's also enough common code in all the three cases that it should really be put into its own function Pass the letter (`which_pile`), the three piles as arguments, then pass the pile to modify by reference. The `player1` and `player2` function could just be a single function as well, passing the string `"one"` or `"two"` as argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line:

```
if(which_pile == 'A' || 'a')
```

You are stating if( 'a' ) and as 'a' converts to a value higher than 0 it will be converted to a boolean with value true. You need to do:

```
if(which_pile == 'A' || which_pile == 'a')
```